# Is it efficient to read, process and write one line at a time?

Tags: algorithm, performance, file, big-o

I am working on a project requires reading a file, making some manipulations on each line and generate a new file. I am a bit concerned about performance. Which algorithm is more efficient? I wrote some pseudocode below.

1. Store everything to an array, close the file, manipulate each line and store new array to output file:

   ```
   openInputFile()
   lineArray[] = readInput()
   closeInputFile()

   for (i in lineArray) // i:current line
       manipulate i
       newArray[] += i // store manipulted line to new array

   openOutputFile()
   writeOutput(newArray)
   closeOutput()
   ```
2. Get each line in a loop, after manipulation write new line to the output

   ```
   openInputFile()
   openOutputFile()

   for (i in inputFile) // i:current line
       manipulate i
       print manipulated line to output

   closeInputFile()
   closeOutputFile()
   ```

Which one should I choose?

Comment: I would go for the first one: hard drive performances may be bad if you read&write sequentially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how large the input file is:

- If it is small, it doesn't matter which approach you use.
- If it is large enough, then the overhead of holding the entire input file and the entire output file in memory at the same time can have significant performance impacts.  (Increased paging load, etcetera.)
- If it is really large, you will run out of memory and the application will fail.
- If you cannot predict the number of lines there will be, then preallocating the line array is problematic.

---

Provided that you use buffered input and output streams, the second version will be more efficient, will use less memory, and won't break if the input file is too big.

Answer (score 2):

In both cases you read from each file once, and write to each file once. From that perspective, there isn't much difference in efficiency. Filesystems are good at buffering and serialising IO, and your disks are almost always the limiting factor in this sort of thing.

In an extreme case, you do *sometimes* gain a bit of efficiency with batching your write operations - a single large write is more efficient than lots of small ones. This is very rarely relevant on a modern operating system though, as they'll already be doing that behind the scenes.

So the key difference between the two approaches is memory use - in the former case, you have a much larger memory footprint, and gain no advantage from doing it. You should therefore go for the second choice*.

* Unless you actually need to reference elsewhere in the array, e.g. if you need to sort your data, because you then *do* need to pull your whole file into memory to manipulate it.